# In 1 Samuel 20:30.. Is Saul saying: "SON of a *****?"?

Tags: 1-samuel, saul

After reading those verses from 1 sam 20:1-30, it seems like Saul is actually Screaming: You "SON of a *****?"?... but the Bible writers or translators seems to polish that verse with seemingly "Polite" words... by saying things like son of a rebellious woman etc...

Comment: There is a site for these type of questions: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: After rereading this, I -1 because I feel that the question is more rhetorical in nature.  You can read the various translations and see how the translators / transliterators(?)  attempted to express the passage in the same meaning as it meant to a first century Jew using more modern vocabulary.  You suggest that he is saying, "son of a bitch" however consider this: in a thousand years people will be asking, "what does it mean to be a son of female dog?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about confirming a speculation about the meaning of an OT passage. [Hermeneutics.se] might be better.

Answer (score 3):

According to [BibleHub.com's "Hebrew Text Analysis Page"](http://biblehub.com/text/1_samuel/20-30.htm), the Hebrew text is

> בֶּֽן־נַעֲוַ֖תהַמַּרְדּ֑וּתהֲל֣וֹאיָדַ֗עְתִּי

and a literal translation is something along the lines of

> son of the perverse rebellious [woman]

Thus it appears that this is what Saul in fact did say, although he may have meant, as the New Living Translation has it,

> You son of a whore!

or as the New English Translation (NET Bible) says,

> You stupid traitor!

The Douay-Rheims Bible seems to be getting at the same thing the NLT wants to say, though in 16th-century language:

> Thou son of a woman that is the ravisher of a man!

But though Saul may have *meant* this, there's no indication that he actually *said* it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to take "said to [Jonathan]" other than having it *said* by Saul.

Comment: @user2864740 in other words, Saul may have meant to imply that Jonathan was a "son of a bitch" or "of a whore", but he doesn't seem to have actually said that and had it "polished up" by translators.

Comment: Well for that matter, what kind of impact would calling your mother a "perverse rebellious woman" have? Would it be the same as calling her "whore"?

Answer (score 3):

Not all translations 'polished' [1 sam 20:1-30](http://biblehub.com/1_samuel/20-30.htm); These are them:

1.New Living Translation:

Saul boiled with rage at Jonathan. "You stupid **son of a whore**!" he swore at him. "Do you think I don't know that you want him to be king in your place, shaming yourself and your mother?

2.NET Bible:

Saul became angry with Jonathan and said to him, "You stupid traitor! Don't I realize that to your own disgrace and to the disgrace of your mother's nakedness you have chosen this son of Jesse?

3.Douay-Rheims Bible:

Then Saul being angry against Jonathan said to him: Thou son of a woman that is the ravisher of a man, do I not know that thou lovest the son of Isai to thy own confusion and to the confusion of thy shameless mother?